# Setup Core Data relationship in ordering app

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I currently have the following relationship set up for my ordering app.

Product <<- Cart

That's working as it should, the product gets added to the cart and so on. When the user has pushed the "order button" in the "cart viewcontroller", I want all these products, which just got ordered to show up, in my other view controller. I want to show all the orders made by the user. But I can't really figure out how to setup my Core data model in order to accomplish this? Do I need a one to one relationship from Cart or a one to many relationship or something completly different?

Thank you for your help.

EDIT 1:

[image]

EDIT 2:

```
+ (ProductOrder *)addProductToOrderWithProduct:(Product *)product inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {


    ProductOrder *orderProduct = nil;

    orderProduct = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ProductOrder"     inManagedObjectContext:context];



    NSManagedObjectID *productID = [product objectID];

    orderProduct.antal = product.antal;
    [(Product *)[context objectWithID:productID] addOrderedProductsObject:orderProduct];

    return orderProduct;

}

    + (Order *)addOrderedProductToOrderWithOrderedProduct:(ProductOrder *)orderedProduct inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {

    Order *order = nil;

      order = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Order" inManagedObjectContext:context];



// THIS SHOULD INCREMNT THE ATTRIBUTE FOR SECTIONS, WHEN A NEW ORDER IS CREATED. 

    NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:order.orderNumber.intValue];
                    int value = [number intValue];
                    number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:value + 1];

                    order.orderNumber =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Order %@", number.stringValue];

                    NSLog(@"%@", order.orderNumber );


        NSManagedObjectID *orderedProductID = [orderedProduct objectID];

        [order addOrderProductsObject:(ProductOrder *)[context objectWithID:orderedProductID]];




        return order; 


    }
```

Add products to order from products in cart:

// Cart products

```
  for (Product *prod in [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]) {


        [[[DataManager sharedInstance] backgroundManagedObjectContext] performBlock:^{

       [Order addOrderedProductToOrderWithOrderedProduct:  [ProductOrder addProductToOrderWithProduct:prod inManagedObjectContext:[[DataManager sharedInstance] backgroundManagedObjectContext]] inManagedObjectContext:[[DataManager sharedInstance] backgroundManagedObjectContext]];


                         prod.antal = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];

                        [self saveCurrentContext:_theManagedObjectContext];
                        [[DataManager sharedInstance] saveBackgroundContext];
                        [[DataManager sharedInstance] saveMasterContext];




        }];



    }
```

Load the orders in "order viewcontroller" from passed order object

```
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"ProductOrder"];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"inOrder.orderNumber" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:_theManagedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"inOrder.orderNumber" cacheName:nil];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;



    NSError *error = nil;


    if (![_fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Fetch Failed");

    }



}
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more? From your previous questions I know that you already have a fetched results controller that shows all products in the cart. How is that different from "all orders made by the user" ?

Comment: Sure, I have tabbar with 3 tabs, one for the displaying the products, then the cart, where I have an order button and this viewcontroller for showing the products ordered by the user. When the order button in the cart is pushed, all the products in the cart is sent to a server - an order is sent and I then want to move/show the products from the cart to my other viewcontroller, to display all the products which is ordered/sent to the server for processing.

Comment: I have thought of setting up a relationship like so: Product <<- Cart <<- Order, so when the order button in the cart is pushed, the products is first sent to the server and then deleted from the Cart - Product relationship and then added to a Product <<- Order relationship .. But I don't know if this is the way to do it? Thank you very much for your help, it's really appreciated :)

Comment: It's different since the products is not ordered yet when they are in the cart, first when the order button is pushed :).

Comment: You could use a "Product <<- Order" relationship. Or you just add a Boolean attribute "ordered" to the Product entity which is set to @YES if the product is ordered. Then you can display ordered products using a predicate like "ordered == %@, @YES".

Comment: Okay, thank you. So it would be okay to first delete the products in the cart by breaking the relationship and then add the same products to a Product <<- Order relationship? .... Would the attribute method be okay, if a product can be ordered multiple times?

Comment: If you have multiple orders, then you probably need a many-to-many relationship "Product <<->> Order".

Comment: Hmmm, I am not sure if that is the case, I have drawed what I want to accomplish, under EDIT in the question above. Is a many to many relation needed here? Thank you for your help again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31832/discussion-between-martin-r-and-seya)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A product can be ordered multiple times, and an order contains multiple products, so the
first idea would be to use a many-to-many relationship:

```
Product <<-->> Order (1)
```

However, if you want to display all orders with their products using a fetched results
controller, then you need to insert an "intermediate" entity:

```
 Product <->> ProductOrder <<-> Order (2)
```

The reason is that a FRC can display each object only once, so with model (1) you could
not display products that are part of more than one order. With model (2), you can fetch
the *ProductOrder* objects and group them into sections by *Order*
(using the `sectionNameKeypath:` parameter).

Comment: In Order to group the orders into sections, do I then need to add an attribute to the "Order" entity and then use this attribute in "sectionNameKeypath:" ? And how would I manage to show the products in my table view, when I fetch from the ProductOrder entity, just through the relationship? Thank you very much for your help :) (Is it better if I open a new question with this, instead of writing in the comments?).

Comment: @Seya: That sounds correct so far. Don't forget to add a first sort descriptor that uses the same property as the sectionNameKeyPath.

Comment: Okay, good :), I can't get it to work though. I have provided my current code under "EDIT 2" above. I have made 2 objective-c categories to create the relationship from Product to ProductOrder and then to Order. I then get all the products in the cart and add them to the relationships and then pass the order object I get from this, to my "order viewcontroller". I fetch the ProductOrder objects and try to set the sections. But only one object of all the objects in the cart is added to the relationship and only one object then only showed in the tableview.

Comment: I Can´t seem to find the mistake (Maybe somthing wrong in the categories I have made?). And again thank you for all your help.

Comment: Your predicate `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"inOrder = %@", self.order];` in the fetched results controller restricts the result set to one order. Perhaps you want to remove that predicate?

Comment: I have removed the predicate and have almost got it all to work. Now I just have a problem incrementing the (order)number, after a new order is started (Right now all orders is placed in the same section). So I can group the orders in sections. Where would be the right place to place the code that increments the value of the attribute in the Order entity? In the objective-c category? My current code is posted above, under EDIT 2 (modified). Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Seya: I would recommend that you could start a new question. (And may I suggest that you improve the code formatting a bit. It is difficult to read with all the empty lines and different indentations.)

Comment: You are right, my other comment was also out of the scope of the initial question. Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.